# Display a score or graph to visualize the degree of conservation of each residue from alignment data

Tags: sequence-alignment

I would like to display a score or graph to visualize the degree of conservation of each residue from the amino acid alignment data.
If possible, I'd like to extract the parts of the game that scored above a certain level.

Is there a tool or source code (python) to do that?

Sorry for my bad English ...

Comment: Why not use one of the many pair-wise alignment web tools? They tend to have nice graphical outputs like that.

Comment: Thank you, which one is the best?

Comment: Just choose one, there is no best.

Comment: OK, I'll use something.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a [logo plot](https://weblogo.berkeley.edu/logo.cgi), e.g.:
[image: https://weblogo.berkeley.edu/examples.html]

I would take @Devon Ryan's suggestion to create a multiple sequence alignment (MSA), and plug that into that logo plot tool (or others, there are many like it).

Comment: Thank you, Max!! How do you think jaview[https://www.jalview.org/About]?

Comment: I have never used JalView but the tutorial says that it has this feature (http://www.jalview.org/tutorial/TheJalviewTutorial.pdf, p.44). I like to use smaller, simpler tools but if you like JalView it should work for making a logo plot.